# how to add zomato rating option in our own app?

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator

I want to add rating option our own application. when users rates then that rating add automatically add in zomato restaurant id.
**Notes:
I was searched but i got only getreviews API from zomato developer page.that shows only 5 latest reviews.
It is possible add zomato rating option in our own app ??**

Comment: ask zomato guys to give an api to add rating

Comment: that one also done. i was mailed to zomato developer support

Comment: Still you want that api, then need to contact to **Zomato developer support** and **need to do it using legal way**, means by making **official documentation or contract** reagrding defining rules against uses api. **(If Zomato want to do like this way)**

Comment: ok thnx i will try that one